# deleting all specific keys found in linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, coding-style, linked-list

I am trying to delete all specific key element in my linked list in one function . 
that is if linked list has  1 2 2 3 4 4 5 5 8 2 6 32 4 6 7 7   then if I pass the function 2 that function delete all the 2's in linked list

my linked list is here

```
class float_list
{
     struct node
    {
        double data;
        struct node *next;
     };
        node *head;
public:

    float_list(void)
    {
        head = nullptr;
    };

    void appendNode(double);
    void print_list();
    void deleteNode(double);

};
```

now my deleteNode(double is here)

```
void float_list::deleteNode(double num)
{
    node *nextptr, *previousptr = nullptr;
    nextptr=head;
    if(!head->data){return;}
    if(head->data==num)
    {
        nextptr= head->next;
        delete head; 
        head = nextptr;
    }
    else
        while(nextptr)
        {
            previousptr= nextptr;
            if(nextptr->data==num)
            {
                previousptr->next = nextptr->next;  
                delete nextptr;
                cout<<"I Found the  --> "<<num<<"  is going to be deleted"<<endl;
                nextptr = previousptr; 
                //nextptr = nextptr->next;
            }
            nextptr = nextptr->next;
        }
        delete nextptr;
        delete previousptr;
}
```

I tried in all different ways but always get accesss violation error . Please give me conceptual and code hints if possible . thanks 
the code is in win32 Vs2010 app

Comment: I also tried while (nextptr->next != nullptr)

Comment: I wish to get it done in O(n)

Comment: You should never use `operator==` to check equality of two floating point numbers, there is an issue with floating point arithmetic - they are not exact, and result might not be as you expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens after the while loop end. Well, nextptr == NULL. delete NULL == problem.

Try this:

```
node *previous = nullptr, *current = head, *temp;

while(current){
    temp = current->next;
    if(abs(current->data - num) < MARGIN_OF_ERROR){
        if (previous){
            previous->next = current->next;
        } else {
            head = current->next;
        }
        delete current;
    } else{
        previous = current;
    }
    current = temp;
}
```

Comment: the MARGIN_OF_ERROR i kept as 0.0001  and tried to delete 3.1 and 3.0 , it never deleted

Comment: The code had some bugs, which I have fixed. Please try again and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues I can trace:

1. You should never use `operator==` to check equality of two floating
   point numbers, there is an issue with floating point arithmetic -
   they are not exact, and result might not be as you expect [not a solution to your problem but definetly an issue]
2. Your `previousptr` and `nextptr` are the same thing [they are both pointing at the same address!]. You should modify `previousptr` before the current iteration. [right before `nextptr = nextptr->next;`]. Because of it, when you delete `nextptr` and later set:

   ```
           nextptr = previousptr; 
           nextptr = nextptr->next;
   ```

You are actually accessing the element you just deleted, which causes your illegal access.

Comment: @sparkling_spark: Step through a debugger and check the line `delete nextptr;`. You will see that `previousptr == nextptr`. So - when you later set `nextptr = previousptr;`, and try to access `nextptr`, you are actually accessing something that you already deleted, which will result in access violation

Answer (score 1):

something like this (pseudo-code)

```
public void removeData( double data )
{
    if ( this.node == null ){ return; }
    if ( this.node->data == data ){
        this.node = this.node.node;
    }
    this.node.removeData( data );
}
```

Comment: can you give a iterative solution ?

Comment: yes, this can be turned into an iterative solution but why not use recursion in a place where it is meant to be used?!

Answer (score 0):

Probably this can be done through recursion, but here is a moving pointer solution:

```
void removenumber(node **head, int value)
{

    node * current;
    node * prev;
    node * tmp;
    current = (*head);

    if ( current == NULL) return;

    prev = current;
    current = current->next;
    while( current!= NULL && current->next != NULL)
    {   
        if ( current->data == value)
        { //remove current
            tmp = current->next;
            prev->next = current->next;
            free(current);
            current = tmp;
            //previous is the same
            continue;
        }

        current = current->next;
        prev = prev->next;
    }

    // now current->next != NULL check it
    if(current!=NULL) //what is current was deleted?
    {
        if(current->data == value )
        {
            prev->next = NULL;
            free(current);
        }
    }

    if ( (*head)->data == value) //remove head
    {
        tmp = (*head)->next;
        free(*head);
        *head = tmp;
    }

}
```